# Making images fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have images that I want to be invisible and then faded in when certain events occur. My jQuery works fine and the elements are positioned correctly, I just can't get the elements to fade in.

When I type in console `$('#img1').fadeIn();`nothing happens.

**CSS**

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 195px;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#img1 {
  left: 270px;
}

#img2 {
  right: 270px;
}
```

Comment: Try setting `display:none` instead of `opacity:0` as per the doc examples: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: none;` instead `opacity: 0;`

http://jsfiddle.net/rLjz1rv0/

Answer (score 0):

Remove opacity: 0, and replace by

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

use [**fadeTo**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/)

```
$('#img1').fadeTo( 'slow', '1')
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/rLjz1rv0/1/